# How to provide blob of graphql schema to aws appsync api?

Tags: aws-cli, aws-appsync

I am trying to use aws appsync api (StartSchemaCreation) to create schema of a new graphql api with the schema of an existing graphql api, that I dumped with GetIntrospectionSchema api of aws appsync. But the --definition param of StartSchemaCreation requires me to provide a blob of graphql schema to create in the new api. I have my graphql schema in .json and .graphql files, but I cannot use them directly, as it gives error "Failed to parse schema document - ensure it's a valid SDL-formatted document."

I need help understanding how can I pass my graphql schema through --definition param of start-schema-creation.

I am using aws-cli StartSchemaCreation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
aws appsync start-schema-creation \
--api-id <your-api-id> \
--definition file://<file-path>
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. The irony is, it conflicts entirely with amazon's own documentation:

"The path should not contain any protocol identifier such as http:// or file://.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html

Comment: I was using 'cat' command to pass the file contents: --definition "$(cat myfile.graphql)". But myfile became too big and bash started to give an error "Argument list too long". Using file://myfile.graphql solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `aws` CLI error message is not overly helpful if the file contains an invalid schema definition, it says simply `Invalid base64: "schema { ...(entire schema file)... }`; in case of doubt, paste the schema file contents into the [AWS AppSync Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/appsync) in the _schema_ section of a new API and click _Save Schema_ to verify.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the definition parameter is expected to be a base64 encoded string of the schema. This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere in the AWS CLI docs, but I found this tidbit [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/APIReference/API_StartSchemaCreation.html#appsync-StartSchemaCreation-request-definition)

Which led me to try this command which worked:

```
aws appsync start-schema-creation --api-id <your-api-id> --definition $(base64 /path/to/schema.graphql)
```